# Kafka Sink Connector Unsupported Source Data Type for Array Fields

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

Current Kafka Sink Connector have some array fields in the schema file

When I setup my sink connector here is the config

```
{"config": {
            "tasks.max:"2",
            "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
            "connection.url":"'"$URL"'",
            "topics": "topic_scheduled, topic_stream",
            "transforms":"ExtractField",
            "transforms.extractField.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
            "transforms.extractField.field":"session_field",
            "errors.tolerance": "all",
            "errors.log.enable": true,
            "errors.log.include.messages": true
           }
}
```

schema file

```
{
 "name":"session_field",
 "type": ["null,string],
"default":null
},
{
  "name":"session_kind",
  "type": "string",
  "description":"map LinkedSession>SessionKind of session source"
}
{
"name": "session_type",
"type": [
  "null",
  {
    "type": "array",
    "items":"SessionType file"
  }
],
"default: null
}
```

DB Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE topic_one 
   row_id serial not null,
   session_field varchar(25),
   session_kind varchar(25),
   session_type varchar(25)
CONSTRAINT table_name_pkey PRIMARY KEY(row_id)
```

Sink connector status I get this error message

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException:
 Unsupported source data type:
ARRAY\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.bindField
(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1436)\n\tat
io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindField(PreparedStatementBinder.java:141)
\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindNonKeyFields
(PreparedStatementBinder.java:135)\n\tat
io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.PreparedStatementBinder.bindRecord(PreparedStatementBinder.java:71)\n
\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.flush(BufferedRecords.java:139)\n\tat
io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:72)\n\tat
io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:74)\n\tat
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:539)\n\tat
10more\n"
```

Based off the Kafka documentation
[regex transform fields documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/overview.html)

Comment: Would be useful if you showed the database schema, but Connect array types aren't supported by the postgres dialect

Comment: @OneCricketeer i updated the db schema and shared a small comment on code type above, in the db schema the code type will then be result as varchar Can you elaborate on what do you mean Connect array types aren't supported by postgres dialect if I set the type in postgres as varchar? Is there a field in kafka connect to change or modify to  maybe using transform?

Comment: In the stacktrace, the dialect (how records get converted to database rows) says GenericDatabaseDialect. So that's just any database. Connect Schemas don't "fix themselves" to adhere to the database schema; you can search in the source code/github issues to see arrays cannot be written to Postgres, too. I don't think there's any existing transformation that will convert an array to a string, but that'll be one option

Comment: @OneCricketeer When you mention Connect Schemas, is that for Kafka Connect for sink connector Is there another option to handle arrays that you know of or anybody

Comment: That's explicitly an object type in the Kafka Connect API. But it's not a limitation of Connect, only Confluent's connector that doesn't support arrays writing over JDBC

Comment: I don't know how Avro union types work in the JDBC connector (since database columns only have a single type), but a CSV would just have schema of `["null", "string"]`, no `"type":"array"` (which is causing your error)

Comment: 1) `{"type": "string", "items": "string"}` isn't valid schema type 2) Sounds like you issues a DELETE request, not a PUT to update the config, but updating the connector will not fix data that is already in the topic that have arrays, so you need to clean out the topic, use a completely new schema, etc

Comment: I assume either of the `topics` of `topic_api_scheduled` or `topic_stream_transition` still have **existing** data that contain arrays? The connector is still trying to read this data even after you update the schema

Comment: Kafka Connect accepts any data type. The JDBC Sink requires a Struct (which are able to be formed from any type, including Avro, JSONSchema, Protobuf). Within the Struct, you just cant have arrays (or nested fields). So, Avro is fine. JSON arrays will not work either, they need to be strings

Comment: If your question is about the S3 sink, I suggest creating a new post after trying it out, but S3 just stores binary data, it requires no structure